# Mouseover Div Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I know it's a little bit easy question to ask but I couldn't figure it out for 1 week; I have a website that is [here](http://www.ajuans.com), and in portfolio section there's a code which changes image to description when mouse is over...

And I want to make it inverted, the description div has to be first I see on that section and when I move the cursor on it I want the image will be shown.

I couldn't figure it out, which div makes that and how to change it to achieve that.

```
<a href="img/plato.jpg" class="work-6-item image-link-2">
                       <img src="img/plato.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="web tasarım uygulaması" />
                       <div class="work-6-overlay">
                          <div class="work-6-overlay-item">
                             <div class="work-6-des">
                                <span class="work-6-top-tit">PLATO FİLM</span>
                                <span class="work-6-line"></span>
                                <span class="work-6-sub-tit">Web Sitesi / İçerik Yönetimi</span>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </a>
```

Comment: Please paste your code here and isolate the problem :)

Comment: I made it, can you please look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is only reversing hover and normal state
Add that at the end of style.css

```
.work-6-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
.work-6-overlay:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
.work-6-des{
    opacity:1
}
.work-6-top-tit,.work-6-sub-tit, .work-6-line {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.work-6-overlay:hover .work-6-top-tit, .work-6-overlay:hover .work-6-sub-tit, .work-6-overlay:hover .work-6-line {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
    -o-transform: translateY(30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
    transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I know it's a little bit stupid question but how can I handle this if I want to show some of the items as before I use and some of them reversed... 

:)

Comment: @ErenAlkan which items?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual code it's difficult to be sure, but it looks like what you want is to simply re-order the li elements inside each div.

```html
<div class="service-1-up effect-up">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="h-center">
        <div class="v-center">
          <h3 class="title-after"><a class="txt-h">GRAFİK TASARIM</a></h3>
          <h4 class="des">Basılı ya da online tüm grafik tasarım ihtiyaçlarınızı, modern tasarım trendlerine uygun ve işiniz için en verimli doğrultuda planlıyor, tasarlıyor ve teslim ediyoruz.</h4>
          <p class="number">01</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="h-center">
        <div class="v-center">
          <img src="img/icon/tablet.png" alt="grafik tasarım">
          <h2 class="title">GRAFİK TASARIM</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```